# use sed replace ""string"\1\"787" to "string"\1\"787" in cygwin

Tags: regex, shell, unix, sed, cygwin

I am trying to search string and replace string in a file. I used the below code:

```
sed -e 's/{"AP_SESSION_ID"\1\"787"}/{"AP_SESSION_ID"\1\"800"}/g' FILE|tee FILE
```

but it is not working and the output is like this:

```
sed: number in \[0-9] invalid
```

My environment is CYGWIN.

sample file is:

`DP_SESSION_ID is a sting for values
DP_SESSION_ID is aplicat
"DP_S42SETTACC_TYPE"\1\"02"
"DP_SAP_CLIENT"\1\"460"
"DP_SAP_COMM_CONNECTION"\1\"JAVA_COMM_TOOL_ANALYZER"
"DP_SAP_CONNECTION"\1\"JAVA_TOOL_ANALYZER"
"DP_SAP_TOOLBI_CONNECTION"\1\"JAVA_TOOLBI_ANALYZER"
"DP_SESSION_ID"\1\"808"`

I want search this  "DP_SESSION_ID"\1\" sting and replace corresponding number like 808 in file prenatally(windows env), and i wand sing line command in windows bat command or perl command i don't want scrip or program

even i have installed  cygwin tool in my server so unix also ok but single line command

server: windows 2008,cygwin x

using tool : datastage server jobs

`perl -pi -e 's{" "DP_SESSION_ID"\1\"808 '"}{' "DP_SESSION_ID"\1\"900 '"'"}g' " file name`

this code is not working

Please give good solution

Comment: When you keep saying `not working`, then you should show us the sample of source file

Comment: please give me solution

Comment: We can't guess, you need show us detail first, that what's the source file you are working on, what error message you get, or just different with your thought.

Comment: What do you really want ? due to lot of \, \1, " it is not easy to know what you exactly want. So, like BMW ask, give some sample of source data and expected result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to "escape" the backslashes by using two in a row:

```
sed -e 's/{"AP_SESSION_ID"\\1\\"787"}/{"AP_SESSION_ID"\\1\\"800"}/g' FILE|tee FILE
```

Otherwise the `\1` is treated as a backreference, and you have no subgroups (parenthesized expressions) to reference.

Comment: tested on cygwin and no more error but certainly not doing what user3308823 want due to missing exact request (sed action is the transposition of the request in first post)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from back-slashes, IMO you also need to escape the quotes.

```
sed -e 's/{\"AP_SESSION_ID\"\\1\\\"787\"}/{\"AP_SESSION_ID\"\\1\\\"800\"}/g' FILE|tee FILE
```

Comment: My environment is CYGWIN.